# Не работает вставка текста после курсора

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Не идет ввод с вирт клавиатуры ... Кто с этим сталкивался подскажите как решить проблему ?

Вот скрипт клавиатуры:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.mybutton').on('click', function() {

             var Paste = $(this).data('paste');
              parseInt(Paste);
            $( "input[type='text']").val() + Paste;
            $( "input[type='text']").val($( "input[type='text']").val() + Paste);
     console.log(Paste)
        });
    });
```

вот разметка :

```
 <form>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш телефон" name="phone" data-mask="+38 (099) 999-99-99" required/>
            <span class="error"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="form-controls">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-red btn-large btn-block   btn-submit" required disabled="disabled">Заказать звонок</button>
            <button class="mybutton" data-paste="1">1</button>
            <button class="mybutton" data-paste="2">2</button>
            <button class="mybutton" data-paste="3">3</button>
            <button class="mybutton" data-paste="4">4</button>
            <button class="mybutton" data-paste="5">5</button>
            <button class="mybutton" data-paste="6">6</button>
            <button class="mybutton" data-paste="7">7</button>
            <button class="mybutton" data-paste="8">8</button>
            <button class="mybutton" data-paste="9">9</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

вот весь код : http://jsfiddle.net/0xL0fctq/45/

Comment: А что конкретно у вас не работает?

Comment: @Vartlok если попробовать ввести , что то з вирт клавы , то в инпуте оно появляется на секунду потом исчезает . То есть ввод с вирт клавы не работает . А с физической всёработает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю вашу проблему, у вас форма сабмититься при нажатии на кнопки. Это решается изменением html:

```
<form>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш телефон" name="phone" data-mask="+38 (099) 999-99-99" required/>
            <span class="error"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="column">
    <div class="form-controls">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-red btn-large btn-block   btn-submit" required disabled="disabled">Заказать звонок</button>
        <button class="mybutton" data-paste="1">1</button>
        <button class="mybutton" data-paste="2">2</button>
        <button class="mybutton" data-paste="3">3</button>
        <button class="mybutton" data-paste="4">4</button>
        <button class="mybutton" data-paste="5">5</button>
        <button class="mybutton" data-paste="6">6</button>
        <button class="mybutton" data-paste="7">7</button>
        <button class="mybutton" data-paste="8">8</button>
        <button class="mybutton" data-paste="9">9</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ну и возможно стоит добавить отдельную кнопку, которая будет отправлять параметры на сервер, если это необходимо.

Comment: похоже проблема ещё и в том, что инпут при вводе с вирт клавиатуры должен быть активен как и при вводе с обычной клавиатуры , иначе не срабатывает скрипт проверки кода , и скрипт маски номера. А можно как то реализовать чтоб при вводе с вирт клавиатуры инпут был активен ?

Comment: Это не поможет. Проверка введенных данных происходит по эвентам, а ваш код просто добавляет в конец текущего значения число. Т.е. вам надо либо эмулировать нажатие клавиш клавиатуры, либо как-то хачить плагин который вы используете для маски (Вообще возможно в плагине есть какие-то методы для работы со значениями).